# Batch: Save directory listing into list-variable

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, dir

I want to take a file from a source directory (`C:\Users\Desktop\Source\Test.xlsx`) and want to replicate it to several folders, all having the same structure. So I have to change just one folder name. All done via one batch file and just one log-file which is created afterwards.

To have dynamically expansion of my batch-procedure here, I want to do a filtering of the elements of the root folder (`C:\Users\Desktop\Replica\`), which shows me the childs (`one` `two` `three` `four` `five`) where the file needs to be copied at inside a `testfolder`. There I have done the following at the moment, which is static:

```
set "list=one two three four five"
(
 for %%i in (%list%) do (
  xcopy "C:\Users\Desktop\Source\Test.xlsx" "C:\Users\Desktop\Replica\%%i\testfolder" /Y  
 echo(%%i
 echo(
)
)>copylog.txt
```

So, my question is basically who I do the listing of just the folders under "replica" and put those inside a list variable I can use in the code as already written. I only found sources where these are just saved within a separate .txt-file, but I just want to keep it inside the batch.

Any guesses on this one?

By the way: I experienced by saving a path just as a variable, I couldn't execute `xcopy %source% %target%` (even when having "`%source%`" or `source = "Path"`). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search the directories, put them into a variable and then iterate over the values in the variable. Just iterate over the directories

```dos
...
for /d %%i in ("C:\Users\Desktop\Replica\*") do (
    xcopy /y "C:\Users\Desktop\Source\Test.xlsx" "%%~fi\testfolder"
...
```

The `for /d` will iterate over the indicated set of directories. In the `xcopy` command `%%~fi` is used to retrieve the full path of the directory for the current iteration.

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I just forgot the /* idea... Batch is relatively new to me - even while it's old.